# Getting the memory address of the current app in memory

Tags: winapi

How can I get the memory address of the current app (exe, first loaded module)?

GetModuleHandle(), GetModuleInformation() etc seem to return information from the PE header and not the actual address into which the exe is loaded.

Comment: Perhaps you're struggling with the concept of *virtual* address space. It's possible/normal that every instance of an executable is based on the same address.

Comment: Try linking your app with [DYNAMICBASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff820372.aspx).  Then its (virtual) base address will be different each time you run it.

Answer (score 4):

`GetModuleHandle(NULL)` returns an `HMODULE` for the executable module. An `HMODULE`'s value is the base address of the module.

> `GetModuleHandle()`, `GetModuleInformation()` etc seem to return information from the PE header and not the actual address into which the exe is loaded.

That is not correct. The values returned by both of these functions are for the specific module instances as loaded in memory.

Comment: Agreed, I don't know what I was doing wrong before.